# How to setup cocoapods?

Tags: ios, xcode, installation, cocoapods, executable

I installed cocoapods for an iOS project, but when I wrote this command `pod setup --verbose` nothing happened, so I tried some other code but it got worse, and now when I setup cocoapods I get this error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:275:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem cocoapods (>= 0.a) with executable pod (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:252:in `bin_path'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Have you followed the article here - https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html It looks like you do not have cocoapods gem installed

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what happened, but the usual procedure of installing Cocoapods and setting it up is as follows:

**Installing Cocoapods**

1. Open Terminal
2. Type `sudo gem install cocoapods`
3. Type your password and wait for it to finish

**Initializing Xcode project for Cocoapods**

1. In terminal, switch to your project's directory using the `cd` command
2. Type `pod init`. This will add a Podfile to your project, which you can open and add the pods you want.
3. Type `pod install`. This will also generate a `.xcworkspace` file along with your `.xcodeproj` file, and you should always use the former from now on.

With your situation where it seems like pod was either not installed or not installed properly, I suggest you try `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` first to remove everything that *might* be present, then follow the steps above. Also, if that fails, please check that you have the lastest version of Ruby installed.